# Sending a prop using sync and binding it using v-model in child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with BootstrapVue to get this Accordian like component to work. Part of that entails setting the visibility of a particular item.

Ie,

```
const obj = {
   someData: [...// properties here],
   visible: false
}
```

And this gets fed down to an Accordian component like so:

```html
<Accordian :visible.sync="obj.visible" />
```

And inside Accordian:

```
props: {
  visible: {
    type: Boolean 
  }
}
```

THEN... I need to attach it to a `b-collapse` html tag using v-model because that is how it is suggested on their [site](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse). But that throws me this very long list of 'don't modify props directly error'

```html
<b-collapse v-model="visibile" />
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: And an important part I forgot to mention, the error only occurs on initial page load. Afterwards the accordian's are fine to use and work (most of the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `v-model` with a prop because props are meant to be readonly.

Instead, bind `<b-collapse>.visible` to the `visible` prop, and emit the `update:visible` event with the event data whenever `<b-collapse>.input` event occurs. The `update:visible` event updates the parent's `visible` prop via the `.sync` modifier.

```html
<b-collapse :visible="visible" @input="$emit('update:visible', $event)">
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-sync-modifier-with-b-collapsevisible-gbi8y?file=/Accordion.vue:302-378)

Comment: Your solution works! Though I simply passed the :visible="visible" prop and left it at that :)